# How to let user leave blank textboxes that are assigned as Char

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I'm very new to C# and trying to develop a GPA calculator. It has 10 textboxes and another textbox to enter the number of courses. It works fine when the user enter all 10 grades, but when the user enter less than 10 grades, it shows the error - 'Unhandled Exception has occurred in your application'

The part of the code -

```
        TextBox[] boxes = { txbCourse1, txbCourse2, txbCourse3, txbCourse4, txbCourse5, txbCourse6, txbCourse7, txbCourse8, txbCourse9, txbCourse10 };

            //use of a loop to go over the array and find GPA for each course
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            input = Convert.ToChar(boxes[i].Text);

            if (input == 'A' || input == 'a')
                GPA = GRA;
            if (input == 'B' || input == 'b')
                GPA = GRB;
            if (input == 'C' || input == 'c')
                GPA = GRC;
            if (input == 'D' || input == 'd')
                GPA = GRD;
            if (input == 'E' || input == 'e')
                GPA = GRE;
            if (input == 'F' || input == 'f')
                GPA = GRF;

            total += GPA;
        }

        //output to the user (cumulative GPA)
            cumGPA = Math.Round(total / number,2);
            lblGPA.Text = "The Cumulative GPA: " + cumGPA;
    }
```

Comment: Per marked duplicate, you can't pass empty strings to `Convert.ToChar()`. You need to check the input and not call that method if the input will be invalid. If you have made some attempt to actually do that, you need to provide those details, including a good [mcve] that clearly shows what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Comment: I have 'input' variable as Char and it doesn't accept the blanks from the user. When I tried changing 'input' as string, it doesn't let me use the current if statements:
if (input == 'A' || input == 'a')
                    GPA = GRA;

Comment: Just before `input = Convert.ToChar(boxes[i].Text);` check for empty `Textbox` with `if (boxes[i].Text == '')` this if statement has to end after `total += GPA;`

Comment: Any particular reason you don't declare `input` as a `string` instead, and then assign `Text` property directly to it, and finally compare e.g. `input == "A" || input == "a"`?